# Getting the data from function out to display on the admin in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I need to display the data from the function which sits inside a model. In the example below, i would like to get the adult of the student which in the getAdult function. What should go inside the ?? to get the data..

```
models.py:

    class Student(models.Model):

        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        age = models.IntegerField(blank=True,
                                  default=0)

        birthday = models.DateField(blank=True,
                                    null=True)
        school = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                  blank=True,
                                  default='')
        def getAdult(self):
            try:
                adult = self.relationships.filter()[0].adult

                return adult
            except IndexError:
                return None
```

admin.py:

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from school.models import Student

    class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display=('name',??)
```

Please pardon me if the question is stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getAdult` method should return a string. I'm not sure what type of object `adult` is, so I'm assuming it `str()` will return string representation for it.

You can do like this:

```
class Student(models.Model):
#your stuff

    def getAdult(self):
        try:
            adult = self.relationships.filter()[0].adult
            return str(adult)
        except Exception:
            return ''
    getAdult.shot_description = 'Adult'

class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('name', 'getAdult')
```

For more information refer: [list_display in ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Update (if object doesn't have builtin string representation)

```
#example Adult model
class Adult(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age  = models.IntegerField()

class Student(models.Model):
    #other stuff
    def getAdult(self):
        try:
            adult = self.relationships.filter()[0].adult
            return '%s %s' % (adult.first_name, adult.last_name)
        except Exception:
            return ''
    getAdult.shot_description = 'Adult'

class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('name', 'getAdult')
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. what if it is not a str object, can i do the manipulation on getAdult like this:  list_display=('name', 'str(getAdult)')

Comment: @lakesh in that case also `getAdult` should return a string rather than object, you can do your manipulation in `getAdult`.

Comment: my question is assuming that the getAdult function doesn't return a string, can u do the manipulation in the StudentAdmin function? manipulation in the sense, converting to the str(adult)? is it possible?

Comment: @lakesh check the updated answer, basically you can create string from  appropriate attributes of object.